# Existence of two primes satisfying the given conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to know whether 
the equation 
$x^a-x=y^b-y$
has a solution or not satisfying the conditions that $x$ and $y$ are distinct odd primes, $a$ and $b$ are integers both greater than $1$.

Comment: Just a remark of probably no relevance or help:  if the equation had *plus* signs, it would have $5^2+5=3^3+3$ as a solution.

Comment: On a similar note, the equation $x^a-x=k(y^b-y)$ has solution $3^5-3=2(5^3-5)$

Comment: It would help to know what you've tried (e.g., have you conducted a search for "small" solutions, or considered congruence conditions?) and, perhaps, why you want to know.  In particular, if this is part of some research you're doing, it might make sense to move it over to MathOverflow.

Comment: I'm not yet that advance in number theory. I come across that while giving an amateur attempt in Goldbach's conjecture by trying induction on the number of prime factors that doesn't divide n(the even number as 2n). I mostly tried to prove that equation has no solution by the most elementary means.

Comment: But now it is mostly curiosity that I want some answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$13^3-13=3^7-3=2184$$

I should say how I found this.  It came from looking at Section D9 ("Catalan conjecture") in Richard Guy's magnificent *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* (third edition, pg. 238), where he writes:

> "Leech asks if there are any solutions of $|a^m-b^n|\lt|a-b|$ with
>   $m,n\ge3$.  With equality he notes $|5^3-2^7|=5-2$ and
>   $|13^3-3^7|=13-3$.  Are these all? are the shared exponents $3$, $7$
>   significant?"

Unfortunately there's no reference given for Leech.

Its presence in *UPNT* suggest the *general* problem of finding *integer* solutions to $x^a-y^b=x-y$ with $a\gt b\gt1$ is difficult.  The OP's restriction to (odd) *primes* $x$ and $y$ might make things easier, or it might not.  In any event, there is at least one solution; if there are others, my guess is they're likely to be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Bennett, On some exponential equations of S. S. Pillai, Canadian Journal of Math. 53 (2001) 897-922, reports eight solutions of $x^a-x=y^b-y$ in positive integers, with $a,b>1$:

$6=2^3-2=3^2-3$,
$30=2^5-2=6^2-6$,
$210=6^3-6=15^2-15$,
$240=3^5-3=16^2-16$,
$2184=3^7-3=13^3-13$,
$8190=2^{13}-2=91^2-91$,
$78120=5^7-5=280^2-280$,
$24299970=30^5-30=4930^2-4930$.

See the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A057896) for links. I don't think any new ones have been discovered, and I don't think anyone has proved there are none. Of those eight solutions, the only one satisfying the (rather unmotivated) primality stipulations is the one Barry reported in his answer five years ago.